# What is the best way of handling non-validating SSL certificates in C#

Tags: c#, http, ssl

I'm using the following code to make sure all certificates pass, even invalid ones, but I would like to know if there is a better way, as this event gets called globally and I only want the certificate to pass for a certain HTTP call and not for any others that are happening asynchronously.

```
// This delegate makes sure that non-validating SSL certificates are passed
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object certsender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors error)
{
   return true;
};
```

The code above is just an example of ignoring any non-validation on the certificate. The problem that I'm having is that it is a **global** event. I can't see  which session the event is happening for. I might have a couple of http requests going through and I want to ask the user for an action **for each request**.

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the whole purpose of securing your communications with TLS/SSL?

Comment: No - it just opens you up in Man In the Middle (MITM) attacks - you still get the on the wire encryption (which, IMHO is the most important anyway).

Comment: I think I better explain my question a bit more - will edit...

Comment: Well, I guess if your threat model only includes passive attackers, then you don't need to fear MITM attacks, but, in general, MITM attacks aren't hard to perform so excluding them from the threat model isn't worth it.

Comment: Well the actual idea is to give the user the choise of whether to go on or not, kind of like TortoiseSvn does. But I thought I'd solve on problem at at time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the `certsender` argument? Does it contain anything sensible so that you can tell what connection the callback is happening for? I checked the .NET API but it doesn't say what the argument is supposed to contain...

Comment: Funny enough I thought I did check it but I went back because of this post and yes, certsender is actually the HttpRequest object which helps immensely. Thanks for making me check again ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could actually bother to check some of those parameters. ;) For instance, if you have a self signed certificate, then only let [error == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslpolicyerrors) through. You could also check the issuer, name, etc. on the certificate itself for additional security.